# Set an @EnvrionmentVariable from within an ObservableObject helper class

Tags: swiftui, core-bluetooth

I am using CoreBluetooth in SwiftUI and want to set the CBPeripheral use it throughout the app. Using a wrapper class as an EnvironmentObject seems like the right way to go, however I am not sure how to set it from within the ViewModel.

```
class BluetoothViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
    @Published var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
        self.centralManager?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func connectToDevice(btPeripheral: CBPeripheral) -> Void {
        print("trying to connect to \(btPeripheral.name ?? "unknown")")
        centralManager?.connect(btPeripheral, options: nil)
    }
    
    func disconnectDevice(btPeripheral: CBPeripheral) -> Void {
        print("trying to disconnect to \(btPeripheral.name ?? "unknown")")
        centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(btPeripheral)
        // WOULD LIKE TO SET THE @EnvrionmentObject TO nil HERE
    }
}
```

...and after the connection:

```
extension BluetoothViewModel: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            print("powered on")
            self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        } else {
            //need to put an alert here to check bluetooth
            print("powered off")
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
      
        print("connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "unknown")")
        connectedPeripheral.peripheral = peripheral
        // WOULD LIKE TO SET THE @EnvrionmentObject here
    }
    
}
```

This way in the view I show the Bluetooth device

```
    @EnvironmentObject var connectedPeripheral: ConnectedPeripheral
    @ObservedObject private var bluetoothViewModel = BluetoothViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
    
        if (connectedPeripheral.peripheral == nil) {
            BluetoothDevicesView(). //this is where I list the devices and allow for selection
        } else {
            Text("We have one")
            Button("Disconnect") {
                print("pressed")
                // DISCONNECT DEVICE HERE
                bluetoothViewModel(connectedPeripheral.peripheral)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
```

The wrapper class would be basic

import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth

```
@MainActor class ConnectedPeripheral: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var peripheral: CBPeripheral? = nil
    
}
```

I didn't think having the ViewModel as an EnvironmentVariable would be the right way to go and I need to use the CBPerpheral in other views as well. I also would probably just turn the ViewModel into some sort of helper class.

I was also thinking of potentially setting the @EnvironmentVariable by having a @Published object in the BluetoothViewModel, but would not know how to watch for it to change. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why not have `ConnectedPeripheral` be owned by `BluetoothViewModel`? Then inject just the connected peripheral by `.environmentObject`

Comment: Thanks, @jnpdx. Let me try that. Just need to figure out the "inject" part of that.

Comment: `.environmentObject(bluetoothViewModel.connectedPeripheral)` once you have it set up as an instance variable on `BluetoothViewModel`

Comment: I'm having all kinds of problems with this such as: Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context

What is the most common way to create an app with a Bluetooth peripheral. Do you keep the whole viewmodel with the CBCentralManagerDelegate class as an EnvironmentObject or use it to set a CBPerhipheral EnvrionmentObject like I am trying to do?

Comment: I doubt there is a "most common way."